# Adding a second Github Custom Domain

Tags: github, github-pages

I created the repository username.github.io redirected to username.io brought with Namecheap. I got another domain username.me, so I was wondering how to use GitHub pages to add content to that domain without having to create another GitHub account.

Comment: Given that it's your username: no, of course you can't.

Comment: I just used the username.me as an example

Comment: No, I mean it's *your username*. It seemed likely that your username wasn't `username`.

Answer (score 0):

Github pages supports only [one domain](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#multiple-domains-in-cname-file) per user. The only way to use two domains is

> set up redirects through your DNS provider.

You can contact your DNS provider and ask which redirect options are supported.